# How to avoid instance attribute key defined outside __init__ when inheriting?

Tags: python-3.x

What is the best practice when it comes to overloading attributes you inherit from another class? My IDE and linters going bonkers a bit over the fact the attribute I'm overloading does not exist in the init.

```
class MeleeCombatSession(Script):
    def at_script_creation(self):
        self.key = "melee_combat_session"  # Warning
        self.desc = "Session for melee combat."  # Warning
        self.interval = 5  # Warning
        self.persistent = True  # Warning
        self.db.characters = {}  # No Warning
        self.obj.ndb.meelee_combat_session = self  # No Warning
```

I can't really quote the inherited classes because there is about 5 or so classes being inheriting here where the key attribute for example is defined within some methods of other classes. But they all define to this class __init__:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    typeclass_path = kwargs.pop("typeclass", None)
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.set_class_from_typeclass(typeclass_path=typeclass_path)
```

I've tried a number of things, but ideally how I'm supposed to define my MeleeCombatSession class is to set the key, description, interval of this script, and if it's persistent or not, which is overloading the children/parent classes it inherits. I can't for example, pop these into it's own init.

One suggestion was to super() it like:

```
super().__init__("melee_combat_session")
```

The code all works fine. There are no errors or issues. This is how you define the class in the engine I'm working in. Just want to avoid linting issues, which everyone is saying to ignore.

Comment: You shouldn't rewrite  your code because the linter is bad. You should ignore them. Which you can do by physically ignoring them, or disable them. You should be able to disable them per line basis, per file, per project or globally.

Comment: Would that be wise to do though? I was told mixed opinions on this because technically, you don't know if the attributes are initialized or even exist in my codes case, which breaks a few rules in certain standards?

Comment: Well, do you know if the attributes exist and are initialized? If they aren't, then you have an error. If they are, then you don't have a problem. Linters are just there to give you warnings about potential problems. They can be (and not to rarely are) wrong.